# Can we have proper syntax-highlighting for [GLSL]?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

From the excerpt:

> The OpenGL Shading Language (GLSL) is the standard programming language for shaders in OpenGL.

While [glsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glsl) is officially derived from C, it reserves many C++ keywords and otherwise has many significant differences. Also, it has a completely [different use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8664695).

Among others, the one and only proper prototype for `main` there is:

```c
void main()
```

As it is its own, independent language, can we enable proper syntax-highlighting for it please?

`lang-c` should work well enough.

Comment: BTW: Many GLSL-questions are mis-tagged C and/or C++ as well / instead. Probably also due to the missing syntax-highlighting.

Comment: You can add `<!-- language: lang-c -->` above a code block instead of mis-tagging it

Comment: @RobEarl: I know that workaround, but thanks for mentioning that here for others. (I used it in my question).

Comment: The first step would be to [add GLSL to the prettifier](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) then beg them to actually take your patch, then come back and beg SO to pull it and use it. I submitted [a patch for unityscript](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=345&start=100) but so far action from the devs.

Comment: @gman: Using lang-c is a good start. Not sure anything better is needed.

Comment: might be nice to highlight GLSL builtins. `vec4`, `mat4`, `uniform`, `attribute`, `precision` etc. The lang-c one highights `float`. It would be weird to see `uniform float foo;` highlighted but not `uniform vec4 bar;` and beside. It would literally take less than 30 minutes to add glsl support. Just clone the c one and add the keywords. In other words, don't be lazy when the right thing is so easy.

Comment: @gman The problem with that is then you have this almost-an-exact-clone of something else that takes up a bunch of extra characters in the JavaScript file that gets served to every visitor. Even if it's extremely easy to do, Stack Exchange might not be interested in increasing the file's size for a tag that has less than 3,000 questions under its belt.

Comment: @animuson Is it possible to do on a per-site basis then? There are sites where that programming language is a lot more common (relatively, of course. absolutely SO will always lead the question count).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gone ahead and set the code language to lang-c for now.